# How to combine 2 fields on a Facet search - Drupal 9

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I am setting up Facets for my Drupal view and I want to combine and search together on 2 fields: I want the facet to combine field_research_title and field_research_author. Is it possible to setup this way? If yes, how to setup a facet that combines 2 fields of same content type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On facets section /admin/config/search/facets/, you have an option to combine facets.

First, you have to edit one facet to see this option.

[Facets Combined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xK70q.png)

You can combine facets here,You have already tried?

Comment: That visually combines the facets perfectly, but filtering by anything in the second (added) facet does not work, it returns no results.

Comment: UPDATE: Set the order of processors in build stage such that URL Processor handler comes *before* the Combine Processor and it works, at least for taxonomy terms from two vocabularies in two different fields.